# Is putting an array on the heap rather than the stack, going to remove possibilities of segmentation faults?

Tags: c

That is my question. Say my array is size 10, and I get a segmentation fault when I loop through and fill the array to 13, because I corrupted some important information on the stack. If I stuck it on the heap instead, am I immune to segmentation faults? This is more of a conceptual question.

Comment: *"am I immune"* No, you could corrupt something important in the heap as well.

Comment: I wouldn't say you're immune, its more just a throw of the dice as to whether the OS is using the memory addresses adjacent to your array. You often corrupt something in the heap if the OS is using that memory, so I wouldn't recommend doing it

Comment: No.    Insert 13 elements into an array of 10 elements, then the behaviour is undefined, regardless of whether that array is in stack, heap, or any other area of memory.   When behaviour is undefined, there is always a potential of segmentation faults, or other error conditions.    If you want a guarantee, only ever do things that affect the ten elements of a ten-element array.   (Assuming, of course, that all other code also is well-behaved).

Comment: segmentation fault is about accessing invalid segment. Overflow may happen without seg faults, and especially on heap

Comment: Moving off the stack will prevent StackOverflow, not Segmentation Faults. (a wrong pointer address no matter where the thing is stored will still result in an attempt to access memory you do not have a right to access).

Answer (score 1):

No.  If you overrun the allocated space, you are using memory that does not belong to the application, or which belongs to some other part of the application.

What then happens is undefined. I would be surprised in either case if overrunning by just three bytes directly caused a segmentation fault - the page granularity is not that small.  Seg-faults are a function of the processor and operating system not the C language, and occur when you access memory not allocated to the *process*.

In the case of a stack buffer overrun, you will most likely corrupt some adjacent data in the current or calling function, if a seg-fault occurs it will be due to acting upon the corrupted data, such as popping an invalid return address to the program-counter for example, rather than the overrun itself.

Similarly if you overrun the heap allocation, the result depends on what you are corrupting and how that is subsequently used.  Heap corruption is particularly insidious, because the results of the error may remain undetected (latent), or result in failure long after the actual error in some unrelated area of the code - typically when you attempt to free or allocate some other allocation where the heap structures have been destroyed.  The memory you have corrupted may be part of some other existing allocation, and the error may manifest itself only when that corrupted data is utilised.

The error you observe is entirely non-deterministic - an immediate seg-fault is perhaps unlikely in the scenario you have described, but would in fact be the best you could hope for, since all other possible manifestations of failure are particularly difficult to debug.  A failure from a stack data overrun is likely to be more localised - typically you will see corrupted data within the function, or the function will fail on return, whereas a heap error is often less immediately obvious because the data you are corrupting can be associated with any code withing your application.  If that code does not run, or runs infrequently, you may never observe any failure,

The "solution" to your problem is not to write code that overruns - it is always and error, and using a different type of memory allocation is not going to save you from that.  To use a coding practice that simply "hides" bugs or makes them less apparent or deterministic is not a good strategy.